# iOS code organizing pattern

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm fairly new to iOS development. I normally create all my UIViews, UILabels, UIButtons etc. in code instead of using the Interface Builder. This makes it very easy for my UIViewControllers to get extremely large and hard to follow, mixing outlet declarations with actual actions and logic.

```
- (UIButton *) continueButton {
    // if button is nil
    if(_continueButton == nil) {
        UIButton *button        = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain]; 

        /* more configuration */

        _continueButton = button;
    }
    return _continueButton;
}

// occures when continue button is tapped
- (void) buttonTouch:(id) sender
{
    UIButton *button = ((UIButton *)sender);

    if(button == continueButton) {
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

What i want to accomplish is to separate the actual actions, animations, logic and so on,
and store the buttons, labels and other views' declaration in a different file.

As a solution I was thinking of creating another UIViewController with the outlets and embedding it as a child inside the main one which holds the logic, using "addChildViewController".

Would this be the right way to go ? How do you handle it?

Comment: you want to go for a utility kind of controller, which can be reused?

Comment: not really, I'm just wondering what's the best way to separate the logic from the views. I'm coming from a web background, where you have the templates which define the forms and other ui elements, and the controller which handles them.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the interface builder, that's what it is for. Read about dependency injection to get an idea why it is a bad idea to do such things in code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  Using IB is a smart thing to do in most cases.  Xcode will create the code for the UI elements more efficiently then you will.

Also, using IB AND the Assistant Editor will make wiring things up much faster and more efficient.  It also ensures that cleanup code is added where needed.

For code separation within my implementation file, I personally use `#pragma mark -` to separate my Outlet declarations from my Action declarations and then always put the methods for the Actions separate (usually at the top) from the other methods.

I also declare the properties for Outlets privately unless for some reason they need to be public.
My structure:

- My methods at the top
- Actions next
- My delegate methods
- Apple's Methods

Comment: +1 for IB. The best line of code is one you don't have to write.

Comment: Thanks.I'll give one more shot at IB, though to me it seems in some cases somewhat..limited.

Comment: Trust me - you'll thank us for it in the long run. My productivity on UIs is 2-3 times that of other devs I've worked with who refuse to use IB. With experience you'll see how to overcome perceived limitations. Of course, in some cases IB isn't the answer - but in the vast majority of cases you'll find it is.

Comment: Why this practice (generating buttons/labels via code instead of Interface Builder) is a bad idea? At least one advantage I can think of is that you can dynamically adjust your view.

Comment: Unless you need to dynamically adjust your view (some of which can still be done by auto-layout), a developer is better of letting IB do the UI stuff.